# JSch использование множества команд в одном канале

Tags: java, ssh

Есть такой код:

```
try {
                        while (true) {
                            ((ChannelExec) statchan).setCommand("systemctl status app.service");
                            statchan.connect();
                            while (!statchan.isEOF()) {
                                InputStream inp = statchan.getInputStream();
                                inp.read(buf, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                                String str = new String(buf, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                                serverMessage.append(str);
                            }
                            taTaskLog.setText(serverMessage.toString());
                            if (serverMessage.toString().contains(stop)) {
                                taTaskLog.setText("Service stopped");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStaackTrace();
                        StopApp.setDisable(false);
                        StartApp.setDisable(false);
                        RestartApp.setDisable(false);
                        StatusApp.setDisable(false);
                    } catch (JSchException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

По SSH подключаюсь к машине, и нужно что бы у меня по одному каналу запрос выполнялся несколько раз в цикле(один и тот же запрос).
В коде просто делаю парсинг определенного слова из InputStream.

По итогу в канале команда выполняется только самый первый раз, а в документации ничего про это я не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге помогло это

```
statchan = sess.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec) statchan).setCommand("systemctl status app.service");
statchan.connect();
```